# How to stop root component re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a root component that does:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { mydata: {} }
  }

  getData = () {
    // do API GET
  }

  putData = (data) {
    // do API PUT, then:
    this.setState({mydata: data});

  componentDidMount = () {
    getData();
  }

  render() {
    var { mydata } = this.state;
    return (
      <App>
        <MyComponent mydata={mydata} putData={putData} />
        <AnotherComponent />
      </App>
    )
  }

}
```

The trouble I'm having, is that whenever I call 'putData' from 'MyComponent', the whole of 'App' re-renders.

I've looked into:

1. memoizing (which I dont really understand)
2. using Hooks (useEffect) to move the update and state into MyComponent. But then I enter problems with accessing the data from elsewhere without getting into context (which I can't fathom, and is probably overkill anyway?).

What should I do?

Comment: By default, whenever a parent component re-renders, its child components also re-render. By wrapping your component in [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), you can prevent child component to re-render unnecessarily; it will only re-render if its props or state changes.

Comment: Your `App` component rerenders because you update its state. If you want that `AnotherComponent` wouldn't rerender unnecessarily, you should wrap it with `React.memo`.

Comment: So I can't call the 'getData' from 'componentDidMount', if I don't want it to re-render App every time the state changes? Is there a 'componentFirstMounted'?!

Comment: I really don't get this - I've been through my 'old' react stuff, and that doesn't re render the whole <App/> every time App's state changes, and I can't see anything different?!

Comment: Is there a difference between ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')); and export default App? Does this change the way it's rendered?